# Saving the image of a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

So I have this code:

```
Private Sub button28_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button28.Click
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = PicOuterBorder.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    picFinal.Image = screenshot
    'this takes a screenshot
End Sub
```

`PicOuterBorder` is a picturebox on my form. `PicFinal` is another display picturebox. But this code gets me this:[image: ...] Which is basically a screenshot of a window in the size of PicOuterBorder starting from the origin of my screen. However, `Me.Bounds` instead of `PicOuterBorder.Bounds` works and gets a perefect screenshot of just my form. I want picFinal to have a screenshot of just PicOuterBorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. You have to map the control coordinates to screen coordinates using `PointToScreen`. I have placed `PicOuterBorder` inside the panel `PanelPicture`. `PanelPicture` is without any border, while `PicOuterBorder` can have any type of border style. Below code takes the snapshot of the panel.

```
Private Sub button28_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button28.Click
    Dim graph As Graphics = Nothing
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = Nothing
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap

    Dim location As Drawing.Point = PanelPicture.PointToScreen(Drawing.Point.Empty)
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(PanelPicture.Width, PanelPicture.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(location.X, location.Y, 0, 0, PanelPicture.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    picFinal.Image = screenshot

    graph.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapt your code for something like this:

```
Public Sub SaveImage(filename As String, image As Image, Encoder As ImageCodecInfo, EncParam As EncoderParameter)

Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, filename & ".jpg")
Dim mySource As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
Dim grfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mySource)
grfx.DrawImageUnscaled(image, Point.Empty)
grfx.Dispose()
mySource.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
mySource.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: But first I will need to adapt myself to understand what you said. Make a clarification please.